# How to use Gaana API to play songs?

Tags: api

I was trying to get information about gaana.com API in order to play songs from it.

Can any one help me how to play songs using gaana.com API after getting the data of the particular "track"(song)?

Is it possible playing song with all the API's provided by Gaana?

Comment: hey @vikas you'd like to see this [link](https://market.mashape.com/gaana/gaana)

Comment: Thanks @JaysheelVijayUtekar for listing out here

Answer (score 1):

These are some of the music API which are available, and solves most of the purpose. https://musicmachinery.com/music-apis/

```
Having Categories like
 >>Music Metadata
 >>Discovery / Playlisting
 >>Audio Content
 >>Audio Identification
 >>Audio Analysis
 >>Lyrics
 >>Events
 >>Music Analytics
```